# wordpress social icon div not showing

Tags: html, wordpress

please help, i'm a newbie to wordpress.

i am developing a website using wordpress CMS and fitness-lite theme (https://id.wordpress.org/themes/fitness-lite/). i edited the style.css, header.php, footer.php, and customize.php. it was just html and css editing. and then the problem comes.

in the customization in admin mode, the social icon is shown just like the image below
[image: the social icon is shown]

but in the public view mode, the social icon isn't shown just like this
[image: where is the social icon???]

if checked by the inspect feature in Chrome browser, the respective div is there, but it isn't being displayed
[image]

i haven't add any plugin, so it shouldn't be caused by one.

do wordpress use different html or php file to show the web in admin mode and the public view mode?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use css

```
.social-icons{ display: block !important; }
```

Comment: thanks for your answer. i really appreciate it. 

actually, it caused by a feature of my browser extension (adblock). i has the "block social icon" feature and i forgot to turned it off
how silly i am

Comment: yes sometimes it happens with adblock extention, this may also happens on customer's computer, so you can forcefully display block it.